# Firebase, Obtener datos random?, Crear Filtros Complejos

Tags: nodejs, firebase, ionic, angular, windows

Estoy programando una app parecida a Pinterest y actualmente estoy usando ionic y firebase, pero no se si sea buena idea continuar usandolos, ya que firebase me presenta algunas limitante como el no poder hacer un get Random de una lista de datos o la posibilidad de hacer filtros complejos, y realmente me estoy perdiendo mucho tiempo en funcionalidades muy simples que deberían salir rápido.

1-Alguien me podría explicar como hacer un get Random de una lista de datos con database Realtime.

2-Podrían darme un ejemplo de como hacer filtros complejos para obtener datos muy puntuales.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: forzosamente vas a tener que trabajar con la configuración de servidores, balanceadores, optimización de queries, optimización del gestor de bases de datos; son bastantes temas puesto que por si sola ninguna tecnología te va a dar la respuesta que buscas

Comment: estoy de acuerdo Aldredo pero tu me recomendarías seguir con firebase?

Comment: Firebase es rapido, solo debes de saber como trabajar con el actualmente ofrece el modelo NoSql , y en el modelado común permite crear Index que permiten acceder mas rapido a campos precisos

Comment: utiliza la función index de firebase

Comment: No deberias editar la pregunta, la misma fue cerrada porque era una pregunta completamente diferente y hasta tiene una respuesta. Por favor, haz una nueva pregunta

Answer (score 2):

como estas!?
Te recomiendo informarte sobre

1. Angular.JS
2. Node.JS
3. MongoDB

A travez de estos `frameworks` como `express.JS` se logra crear una pagina web actualmente conocida mas como App. Estos se manejan con Api(REST) lo que logra una velocidad increíble.

Espero haberte ayudado. Saludos, Charly G.

Comment: http://mean.io/

Comment: Error una página web no es lo mismo que una App

Answer (score 0):

**Firebase** 
 Yo diría que lo hicieras con Firebase ya que es una herramienta super ponte y adaptable , con ella puedes hacer una sola estructura de bases de datos y adaptarla a web , android y ios.
La potencia de firebase es ilimitada y con las nuevas adaptaciones , realtime database , autentication , cloud messagin , se puede hacer de todo , ademas es muy facil de usar si ya sabes un poco del tema , el problema con las aplicaciones nativas es que acabara a la larga perjudicando el rendimiento de tu app , por eso te recomiendo que uses firebase en vez de cualquier framework para hacer apps híbridas

Comment: Gracias por el comentario David, creo que seguiré por el camino de firebase, la decisión de usar ionic fue mas que nada por ahorrar tiempo ya que la app es un producto que le urge a mi cliente.